# Capacity of a communication channel

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find the capacity of a discrete memoryless communication channel with the following probabilities:

[image]

This example is completely worked out in my course. But I'm having trouble understanding some parts of it. The complete example is:

We have to find the input distribution that maximizes $I(X;Y)$ in order to find this channel's capacity. We know that:

$I(X;Y) = H(Y) - H(Y|X)$.

$H(Y|X)$ can be found like this:
$H(Y|X) = P(X=a)*H(Y|X=a) + P(X=b)*H(Y|X=b) + P(X=c)*H(Y|X=c)$

Based on the input-output relationship of the given channel, it is clear that for all 3 cases X = a, X = b and X = c, Y a ternary random variable is with probabilities 0.25, 0.25 and 0.5. This means that:

$H(Y|X=a) = H(Y|X=b) = H(Y|X=c) = 1.5$.

The example goes on after this, but I'm having trouble understanding why Y is a ternary random variable with probabilities 0.25, 0.25 and 0.5. I also don't understand where the values $H(Y|X=a) = H(Y|X=b) = H(Y|X=c) = 1.5$ come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H(Y|X=x)$ is just the entropy of $Y$ conditional on the knowledge that the realised value of $X$ is $x$. Hence:

$$H(Y|X=a) = \Pr(Y=a^\prime | X=a) \log \Pr (Y=a^\prime | X=a) + \Pr(Y=b^\prime | X=a) \log \Pr (Y=b^\prime | X=a) + \Pr(Y=c^\prime | X=a) \log \Pr (Y=c^\prime | X=a) $$

Notice, however, that

$$ \Pr(Y=a^\prime | X=a) = \frac{1}{2} $$
$$ \Pr(Y=b^\prime | X=a) = \frac{1}{4} $$
$$ \Pr(Y=c^\prime | X=a) = \frac{1}{4} $$

And so on.

Comment: Ah I see :) Thank you very much!